# How to pinch zoom multiple UIImageViews inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, pinchzoom

I have to pinch zoom multiple images. I have added each of the UIImageView to UIView and added the UIView to UIScrollView. and returning the UIView image viewForZoomingInScrollView: delegate method, but images are not zooming as expected. is there any better way?

Comment: refere this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Touches/Touches.zip

Comment: @keshav same issue here check link here is my code http://pastebin.com/4idGrBXR

Comment: @keshav paste some code here :)

Comment: I took the above reference and it helped me a lot now it is working better....thanks.

Comment: @keshav plz post yr code how its work :)

Comment: UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300.0, 100.0, 500.0, 500.0)];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    scrollView = scrollView;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    scrollView.bounces = NO;
    self.scrollView = scrollView;
    
    self.fullView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 500, 500)];
    [scrollView addSubview:self.fullView];
    
    // Tell the scroll view the size of the contents
    scrollView.contentSize = self.fullView.frame.size;

Comment: CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
    CGFloat scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / self.scrollView.contentSize.width;
    CGFloat scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / self.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat minScale = MIN(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0f;
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = minScale;

Comment: - (void)centerScrollViewContents
{
    CGSize boundsSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
    CGRect frame = self.fullView.frame;
    if (frame.size.width < boundsSize.width)
        frame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frame.size.width) / 2.0f;
    else
        frame.origin.x = 0.0f;
    if (frame.size.height < boundsSize.height)
        frame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frame.size.height) / 2.0f;
    else
        frame.origin.y = 0.0f;
    self.fullView.frame = frame;
}

- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.fullView;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
#define VIEW_FOR_ZOOM_TAG (1)

@implementation [SVViewController][1]

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    mainScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    mainScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    mainScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

    CGRect innerScrollFrame = mainScrollView.bounds;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        UIImageView *imageForZooming = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:  
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page%d", i + 1]]];
        imageForZooming.tag = VIEW_FOR_ZOOM_TAG;

        UIScrollView *pageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:innerScrollFrame];
        pageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
        pageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0f;
        pageScrollView.zoomScale = 1.0f;
        pageScrollView.contentSize = imageForZooming.bounds.size;
        pageScrollView.delegate = self;
        pageScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
        pageScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
        [pageScrollView addSubview:imageForZooming];

        [mainScrollView addSubview:pageScrollView];

        if (i < 2) {
            innerScrollFrame.origin.x += innerScrollFrame.size.width;
        }
    }

    mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(innerScrollFrame.origin.x + 
    innerScrollFrame.size.width, mainScrollView.bounds.size.height);

    [self.view addSubview:mainScrollView];
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return [scrollView viewWithTag:VIEW_FOR_ZOOM_TAG];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
} 

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

@end


  [1]: http://www.lyricspoints.com
```

Comment: Some information would be nice instead of posting just a bunch of code.

Answer (score 0):

- Check the minimum and maximum zoom scale properties of the scroll view. (max should be greater than min for zoom to happen)
- make sure that you are returning the corresponding UIImageView and not the UIView
- Make sure that you have set the scroll view delegate as the object to which you want the delegate messages of the scroll view to be sent, like `viewForZoomingInScrollView:`

Comment: I think you have not set the `scrollView.delegate` as self. So the method `viewForZoomingInScrollView` would not be called.